# drawing line between 2 points

Tags: r

I want to create a geometrical shape with connecting points together .

Comment: point1(x,y) point2(x,y) so u need x1,y1 x2,y2

Answer (score 1):

You can do some math calculations first and figured out the coordinates of all the vertices - 10 points for a five pointed star.

Then you can use `segment` command or just `plot(...,type='l') + polygon(..)` to make it happen.

Here is some [Java hints](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1092919&page=2) showing you how to calculate the coordinates.

Here is an example showing you the idea:

```
plot(c(0,0.5,0,1,1,0), c(0,0.5,1,1,0,0), type="l")
polygon(c(0,0.5,0,1,1,0), c(0,0.5,1,1,0,0), col="grey")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a reason I've still not caught yet, the result goes better with n...

```
star <- function(n){
    x11(width=5, height=5)
v.x <- seq(0, 2*pi - pi/n , length.out=2*n)
v.x[seq(1, length.out=n, by=2)] <- cos(v.x[seq(1, length.out=n, by=2)])
v.x[seq(2, length.out=n, by=2)] <- cos(v.x[seq(2, length.out=n, by=2)])*0.5
v.y <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=2*n - 1)
v.y[seq(1, length.out=n, by=2)] <- sin(v.y[seq(1, length.out=n, by=2)])
v.y[seq(2, length.out=n, by=2)] <- sin(v.y[seq(2, length.out=n, by=2)])*0.5
plot(-1:1, -1:1, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
polygon(x=v.x, y=v.y)
}

# par(mfrow=c(3,3))
# for (k in 1:9){
#    star(k*5)
# }
n <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter n corner > ")) ; star(n)
```

Save the script then source it. That is it. Yet the stars of 3 -> 10 branches will look awful. Hope it will give you some ideas

[image: Commented lines result]

Comment: thanks, but the point is that, I just want it get the n as input parameter (number of corners in star) from user and just plot that star. could you guide me how can I modify this to achieve that ? in other word, draw n-cornered star where n is input parameter

Comment: I'm no sure to understand very well but if you need to take n from a keyboard input, just add in your script, at the end of the star function definition: n <- readline(prompt="Enter n corner > ") ; star(n)

Comment: yes, sure, but the point is that, when user inter n=3, he just get on star with 3 corner,or when enter n=10, he get one star with 10 corner . but I don't know how to add this functionality to your code.

Comment: I've got non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: I modified the code and it works. You could give a more explicit title to your question by mentioning the keyword "star" for example.